# Bootstrap Search on Nav bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, search, navbar

This has to be such an easy question, but it is eluding me.  In my Nav Bar I have a search box with search button.  How do I make it functional?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" name="searchBox" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am imagining it is a JavaScript, but cant figure out how to make get the string from the text box and then use that string in a GET variable for a new page, such as

`search.php?search=stuffgoeshere`

Comment: Form contents are posted to `search.php` either via GET or POST method. You need to add form tags.

Answer (score 1):

To make it functional, you need to use form tags. Where are you form tags?

Look at the example below:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```